# What factors affect the droplet size in a liquid stream?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am conducting an investigation into the effect of height of jet impingement on the distance of the hydraulic jump from the stagnation point. Does increasing the height of the jet increase the size of the droplets formed? I am ranging the heights from 10 cm to 90 cm.